# Detecting broken sensors with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I'm new to machine learning.

I've got a huge database of sensor data from weather stations. Those sensors can be broken or have odd values. Broken sensors influences the calculations that are being done with that data.

The goal is to use machine-learning to detect if new sensor values are odd and mark them as broken if so. As said, I'm new to ML. Can somebody push me in the right direction or give feedback to my approach.

The data has a datetime and a value. The sensor values are being pushed every hour.

I appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 4):

Since the question is pretty general in nature, I will provide some basic thoughts. Maybe you are already slightly familiar with them.

1. Set up a dataset that contains both broken sensors, as well as good sensors. That is the dependent variable. With that set you also have some variables that might predict the Y variable. Let's call them X.
2. You train a model to learn te relationship between X and Y.
3. You predict, based on X values where you do not know the outcome, what Y will be.

Some useful insight on the basics, is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elojMnjn4kk&list=PL5-da3qGB5ICeMbQuqbbCOQWcS6OYBr5A

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Any ideas on what model is best suitable for this case?

Comment: To be honest, there is no way to tell at this point. But since the fitting, instanciating and predicting all work the same for several models, it's pretty low effort to switch. I would try SVM, random forest and logistic regression. If my answer was helpful, please accept it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Isolation Forest to detect abnormal readings. 
Twitter has developed a algorithm called ESD (Extreme Studentized Deviate) also useful.
https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection/

However a good EDA (Exploratory data analysis) is needed to define the types of abnormality found in the readings due to faulty sensors.

1) Step kind of trend, where suddenly the value increases and remains increased or decreased as well

2) Gradual increase in the value compared to other sensors and suddenly very high increase

3) Intermittent spike in the data